# Probability distribution for heavy zero, right skewed data

Tags: r, probability, distributions, multiple-regression

My question is almost identical to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/is-there-a-distribution-appropriate-for-a-continuous-variable-skewed-toward-zero). I'm searching for a probability distribution for skewed data that allows for zeros.  The purpose is to fit a GLM model.  My data on species-area distributions are heavy right skewed.  Additional variables are "partitioned area" according to latitude- so area in tropical and temperate zones, thus the data now includes zeros.

So my question is; is there a probability distribution, e.g. similar to the log-normal, but which allows for zeros?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Histograms of my area data

[image]

Comment: The [Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) is the canonical example, but perhaps you should post a histogram with your data so we can get more of a feel? Gamma regression isn't the most common GLM, but it may be very appropriate here.

Comment: It's not clear, but you might be looking for *zero-inflated* models (which you can search about).

Comment: Unfortunately I said Gamma regression forgetting that $0$ is not in the support of the Gamma distribution. @whuber has the right of it

Comment: I got suggested this paper on "The compound poisson-gamma model" which is appropriate for skewed, zero-inflated continuous data. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12122/abstract

Answer (score 1):

The tweedie distribution is in the exponential family, hence can be used in a GLM context, and it allows for the occurrence of zeroes in the response variable. You could see if this suits your purpose.