# Covariance matrix estimation in presence of missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, covariance-matrix

I want to estimate a covariance matrix from data with some missing values. Ideally I'd like an R package but python could be ok.

R has some built in ways of doing this. You can use

```
cov.mat=cov(X,use='pairwise')
```

Or the same using cor (correlation). The trouble is that if you do this with cov, the matrix will not be guaranteed to be positive definite. If you do cov2cor(cor.mat), you will find correlation coefficients outside of [-1,1]. Using pairwise with cor seems to handle this. Then I could use the diagonal variances to go from cor.mat to cov.mat. Still, this is probably not optimal.

There appears to be a few packages that claim to do this (mvnmle, rsem) but neither appear to work. rsem fails to run for me. mvnmle can only handle up to 50 variables. I need to handle roughly 1500 variables. Would like it to run in a few seconds.

Anyone know of a good package for this?

Comment: What error do you get from rsem?  (It might be running out of memory). You could try imputation, but with 1500 variables it's not going to take a few seconds, and it's going to take a big chunk of memory. What's the sample size?

Comment: Error in solve.default(sig0) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.938e-21

Comment: This is a large p, small n problem if that matters.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. rsem expects a positive definite matrix, and if n < p, it won't be.

Comment: I asked a very closely related question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1781, which concerns missingness due to censoring. If your form of missingness is completely at random, it could be viewed as complete censoring, whence any useful answer to my question (should one ever appear!) ought to apply here too.

Comment: The fastest approach I'm familiar with is FIML (see http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2280845?sid=21105125859661&uid=3739808&uid=4&uid=3739256&uid=70&uid=2129&uid=2 or http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=225699) . Multiple imputation might work better for your case, but I would agree with Jeremy Miles that it's going to be slower, especially in Python/R. I've seen some people use FIML combined with PCA steps when dimensionality is an issue, but you'd have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the approaches that come to mind.

You can use nearPD function from the Matrix package to convert the matrix output from cov/cor to a positive definite matrix.

You can use an imputation package such as VIM to fill missing data and then use cov.

You can code up your own routine to compute cov estimate using Expectation Maximization under normality. For details you can refer to Rubin.